# SMS via gms modem asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sms, modem

I'm using a gsm modem itengo 3800. I'm currently doing a project that interface with a website to send/receive bulk sms, schedule sms and etc.

The problem is, i don't really know which should it be coded in. Should it be coded as a  asp.net web application? or should it coded as a windows programs that interface with the web application for send/receiving sms?

Also receiving/sending multiple sms is important, so i requires queue or anything for buffer? Would be glad if sample programme is provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because sending messages via gsm modem can be slow, what I'd do is have the ASP.NET app post the messages to a message queue, then have a windows service read the queue and send the messages.  This allows the website to avoid any degradation issues when sending out lots of messages.

Here is a decent article that discusses using MSMQ:  http://www.15seconds.com/issue/031202.htm

The ASP.NET app would:

```
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(QUEUE_PATH);
Message msg = new Message("5555551212|message");
queue.Send(msg);
```

And the service would listen:

```
MessageQueue queue = new MessageQueue(QUEUE_PATH);
Message msg = queue.Receive();
```

Comment: this is the first time i'm into asp.net. Do you have any example of the communication between both asp and the windows programmme? For the part when the server send a post and how the windows service react to it?  thank you very much

Comment: Hi for the windows service, it's best to use a seprate programme like wcf or i'll could just create a handler for the Global.asax?

Comment: Separate program.  Create a Windows Service app

Comment: hi. The windows application. i'm developing is on WCF. It will listen for new queue and receive messenges. The problem i'm facing now is when WCF application is listening to new queue, a new message is received, will this result in error?